# counting rows in two related tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables, `A` and `B`, with `B` containing a foreign key pointing to `A`. Both tables have a `flag` column. I am trying to count the number of rows in `A` subject to a condition, that:

1. has flag set
2. has a row in `B` that has flag set
3. or both of the above

I've tried using

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  tableB
  INNER JOIN tableA ON tableA.id=tableB.A_id
WHERE
  (tableA.flag OR tableB.flag) AND
  [condition]
```

where `[condition]` is an unrelated condition. However, this seems to return incorrect counts. What am I doing wrong?

Table A columns: `id` (primary key), `flag`

Table B columns: `id` (primary key), `flag`, `A_id` (foreign key, references `A.id`)

Comment: aren't you checking if both flags are set... `(tableA.flag AND tableB.flag)`

Comment: Is `tableB.A_id` unique in B? if it's not A and B are actually swapping their roles in the count. You'd have to group B first.

Comment: Can you provide the table values?

Comment: @Y.S I've added a list of the relevant columns to the question

Comment: @collapsar no, `tableB.A_id` is the foreign key referring to `A.id`

Comment: You may try another joining keyword `FULL OUTER JOIN` and follow the suggestion for grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM tableA A
WHERE (
    A.flag = 1
    OR EXISTS(
        SELECT 'ROW_IN_B'
        FROM tableB B
        WHERE B.A_id = A.id
        AND B.flag = 1
    )
)
AND [condition]
```

Count all rows in A where A has flag = 1 (true) or exists a row in b with flag =  1 (true).

These two conditions in OR are relationed with the third condition named [condition]